# Primefaces input mask for date converter

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Well. I find in all places and I still without solution. I need to do a input mask with Primefaces and bind the value to a Date object in my bean.

The problem is: I use a converter with all validations, convertions and formats with my own code. My answer is: Is other solution with better performance. I hope so. Please help.

P/D: I don't need use a pickdate. I need the input mask to do this

Comment: You can use inputMask with converter, validator and all formats

Comment: yeah, I know. I think in some "Prime" solution. When a write my solution i have so much code.

Comment: good luck for "Prime" solution

Comment: Thank you, for now I'll do the simplest way to find a more efficient solution . Thank you as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use this:

```
<div style="margin-bottom:1em;font-size: 1.2em;"> 
    <p:inputMask id="dob" mask="99/99/9999" value="#{viewMB.request.dateOfBirth}" style="width:8em;" >
        <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
    </p:inputMask>
    <p:watermark  value="MM/DD/YYYY" for="dob" />
</div>
```

and you can still add custom validator if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is my solution

```
<h:form>
      <p:inputMask mask="99-99-9999" value="#{mask.date}" converterMessage="Invalid Date!" converter="dateconverter" />
      <h:commandButton actionListener="#{mask.submit()}" value="Submit" />
</h:form>
```

And the converter

```
@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
    System.out.println(value);
    if (value != null) {
        try {
            if (validateDate(value)) {
                return convertDate(value).toDate();
            }
            else{
                throw new ConverterException("Invalid date!");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ConverterException("Invalid date!");
        }
    }
    throw new ConverterException("Null String!");
}
@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    System.out.println(value);
    if (value != null) {
        try {
            Date now = (Date)value;
            DateTime d = new DateTime(now);
            return d.getDayOfMonth() + "-" + d.monthOfYear() + "-" + d.getYear();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ConverterException("Convertion failure!");
        }
    }
    throw new ConverterException("Null object!");
}
private boolean validateDate(String param) throws ParseException{
    //Param is a date format from input mask
    String[] values = param.split("-");
    int day = Integer.valueOf(values[0]);
    int month = Integer.valueOf(values[1]);
    int year = Integer.valueOf(values[2]);
    DateTime converted = convertDate(param);
    if (converted.getDayOfMonth() != day || converted.getMonthOfYear() != month || converted.getYear() != year) {
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}
private DateTime convertDate(String param) throws ParseException{
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
   Date convertedCurrentDate = sdf.parse(param);
   return new DateTime(convertedCurrentDate);
}
```

The Managed Bean

```
@ManagedBean(name="mask")
public class MaskBean {

private Date date;

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public void submit(){
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.execute("alert('date submited: value recibed " + date.toString() + "')");
}
```

}

It work for me.

Comment: what datatype is this DateTime  ??